# Why pmatrix in a description list break the document flow?

Tags: matrices, description

The code to provide the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}   
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
% UTF-8 encoding is recommended by ShareLaTex

\title{MWE}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\section{Grande Resumo de Álgebra}

\begin{description}

\item[Igualdade de Matrizes] \hfill \\Duas matrizes são iguais se tem a mesma dimensão e elementos iguais.

\item[Matriz Transposta] \hfill \\Troca de posição as linhas e as colunas.\\
A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -2 & 4 \\ 1 & 3 & 7 \end{pmatrix}
\Rightarrow 
A' = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ -2 & 3 \\ 4 & 7 \end{pmatrix} 

A transposta da transposta é a matriz original.\\
(A^{t})^{t} = A

\item[Matriz Simétrica] \hfill \\Quando a transposta da matriz é a mesma matriz original, dizemos que a matriz é simétrica. A^{t} = A\\
A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 & 6 \\ 2& 10 & -7 \\ 6 & -7 & 9 \end{pmatrix} 

Toda Matriz Simétrica é quadrada.

\item[Matriz Diagonal] \hfill \\É uma matriz que contém zeros em todas as posições fora da diagonal.\\
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 11 \end{pmatrix}

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

I thought why my document flow in the description list has broken, so I have notice that the document flow broke after my first matrix appearence.

Did you guys know how to fix or avoid that?
I want to write a list to summarize some math subjects, but I would like to write some examples inside the list.
I could do that without the list but would give me more work.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help, cheers!!

[image: pmatrix inside description]

Comment: When asking questions you should provide a full  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone. Posting an image is of little help to anyone as it can't be copied & pasted.

Comment: Sorry @Andrew, thanks to cfr the image is now correct.
PS: I'm reading about the MWE, thanks! :D

Comment: Now I think I have something close to a MWE, it's in the pastebin link. @Andrew

Comment: @jacksonbenete I copied your code and placed it directly in the post. It's always better to not rely on external links/content whenever possible, since we cannot guarantee their availability in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you need to enclose mathematics in `$...$` or `\(...\)` for in-line equations and `\[...\]` for displayed equations. As you have not done this your code does not compile (there are errors!) and this leads to the description environment being broken.

In terms of style, rather than using `\\` to insert explicit line breaks it is probably better to put the corresponding equations into display mode. Doing this gives you the following:

[image]

**Edit**
Rather than using `\\\hfil` to force the descriptions onto a new line I recommend using the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. If you load this package then starting your description environment with

```
\begin{description}[labelwidth=\textwidth]
```

will make this happen automatically. Here is the corrected code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% UTF-8 encoding is recommended by ShareLaTex

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[labelwidth=\textwidth]
  \item[Igualdade de Matrizes]
  Duas matrizes são iguais se tem a mesma dimensão e elementos iguais.

  \item[Matriz Transposta]
  Troca de posição as linhas e as colunas.
  \[ A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -2 & 4 \\ 1 & 3 & 7 \end{pmatrix}
  \Rightarrow
  A' = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ -2 & 3 \\ 4 & 7 \end{pmatrix}
  \]
  A transposta da transposta é a matriz original.
  \[(A^{t})^{t} = A\]

  \item[Matriz Simétrica]
  Quando a transposta da matriz é a mesma matriz original, dizemos que a matriz é simétrica. $A^{t} = A$
  \[A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2 & 6 \\ 2& 10 & -7 \\ 6 & -7 & 9
  \end{pmatrix}\]

  Toda Matriz Simétrica é quadrada.

  \item[Matriz Diagonal]
  É uma matriz que contém zeros em todas as posições fora da diagonal.
  \[A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 11 \end{pmatrix}\]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful!
I still have some problems trying to line break in many forms, sometimes I try "\linebreak" and this mess up everything, so I usually spam "\\" to solve almost everything. But this is a subject for another topic and I will study more about line breaking in Latex before.
Really thanks Andrew!